# CGI está em desuso, mas e se eu quiser fazer um sistema web seguro em uma intranet?

Tags: aplicação-web, segurança, lazarus, cgi

Sei que existem muitos meios de criar um sistema web seguro com tecnologias como PHP, .NET e etc, porem estas linguagens interpretadas expõem o código a curiosos quando o sistema deve ser instalado em um servidor cliente por exemplo.
Sei também que existem ofuscadores de códigos, mas confesso que além de tirar a versatilidade do PHP por exemplo, me parece que não são tão seguros quanto uma aplicação compilada.

Essa questão dos código é complicada e leva a muitas discussões infindáveis!
Mas enfim, a necessidade é criar uma aplicação web que possa ser instalada em um cliente mas que os código possa estar seguros caso "alguém" queira mexer, não é nem tanto roubar o código, mas mexer mesmo, isso já daria uma enorme dor de cabeça.

Sei que existem muitas opções como Delphi e Lazarus Web, mas esses fazem uso do CGI o que na minha humilde opinião é muito bom, mas, já sei que é antigo.

Hoje em algumas aplicações eu utilizo templates, onde são divididos os arquivos PHP e HTML, essa forma é muito produtiva e a manutenção é uma delícia.

Meu objetivo neste post é saber se há alguma classe em Pascal ( o que pode ser em Delphi ou Lazarus ) que fizesse uso de templates separando assim o CGI dos arquivos HTML.

Temos alguma coisa nesse sentido?

Já procurei na web, mas achei bastante exemplo usando Delphi e Lazarus, mas no metodo tradicional onde os códigos HTML e Regras de negócios são embaralhados no mesmo fonte, já programei assim, mas confesso que é bem trabalhoso, principalmente a manutenção, chega a ser meio desanimador quando o projeto começa a crescer.

Comment: Voce poderia usar o cgi como uma API, onde o HTML usando angular, vue,  react ou puro que seja, faria requisições pra essa api

Comment: Entendi Edson, mas será que a manutenção desta combinação não vai ser muito trabalhosa?

Comment: Acredito que seja até mais fácil, pois tudo fica bem dividido. Você pode mudar todo o backend sem mexer no front, e vice versa

Comment: Estou percebendo que alguns não entenderam a minha necessidade e gostaria de saber o porque, pelo menos coloquem um comentário para que eu corrija minha pergunta, pesquisei muito na web e o que achei foram varios exemplo de como fazer CGI,mas a minha necessidade é saber se existe um meio de trabalhar com CGI no estilo Codeigniter, a ideia é juntar a versatilidade codeigniter com a segurança do CGI

Comment: Quando você diz "Codeigniter" refere-se ao framework php? Neste caso sua dúvida é sobre a possibilidade de compilar o php ao invés de interpreta-lo?

Comment: Isso esse framework php, apesar de eu não usa-lo ja testei e ele é uma mão na roda, hoje eu uso esse template https://github.com/raelgc/template/blob/master/raelgc/view/Template.php ele faz a separação do php e html é muito leve e pratico, a intenção seria compilar o php, mas pelo que andei vendo por ai não fica bom, tem que usar componentes terceiros e isso é um problema quando repassado para o cliente... a ideia seria criar uma classe template em cgi usando uma linguagem compilada como Lazarus ou Delphi